# How to stop background layering with CSS?

Tags: iphone, css, safari, firefox4

I use background image on `<input type="submit">` to make it look like a button. So I have the following in my CSS:

```
input.button {
    background-image:url(/path/to/image.png);
}
```

Also, I want to show different image when button is disabled, the following CSS should do that:

```
input.button[disabled] {
    background-image:url(/path/to/disabled/image.png);
}
```

The problem is, in iPhone browser that disabled image is drawn **above** the normal one, not instead of it.
I believe it is because CSS3 allows for multiple background images so Safari does it's best at drawing both of them. In fact, FF4 does the same if I use `background` instead of `background-image`. With the code as it is, however, FF4 draws it perfectly.

So, the question is, is there some way to **replace** existing background image in mobile Safari instead on layering it on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved my problem by eliminating transparency from my images and also adding `opacity: 1` to the stylesheet (otherwise mobile Safari made them transparent for some reason)

Kind of intermediate solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both images into a larger one and use the sliding doors technique (using background position to switch between enabled and disabled images).

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, it is still drawing one image on top of another.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS-sprite instead:

```
input.button {
    background: transparent url(/p/2/img.png) no-repeat top left scroll;
}

input.button[disabled] {
    background-position: bottom left;
}
```

Comment: It is still layering on top of another. In fact, with your code even FF4 draws them as such. The way to stop it is to separate `background` shortcut to `background-image` and `background-position`. However, mobile Safari doesn't care either way, it is always one image on top of another.

Comment: what about to separate classes **button** and **button-disabled** - this way only one of both CSS selectors match

Comment: That would be cheating, wouldn't it? :)